# unity3d: object doesn't fly backwards after collision

Tags: physics, unity-game-engine, collision

I have a car with a rigid body running into the model, Lerpz (with no animation), also with a rigid body. I want the car to hit Lerpz and for Lerpz to fly backwards for 3 seconds before disappearing using the following code on the car. Both have colliders (one capsule for Lerpz, one top and bottom of the car).  The Force values are arbitrarily chosen:

```
function OnCollisionEnter(collidedObject : Collision) { 
    Debug.Log("hit");
    if (collidedObject.gameObject.tag == "Lerpz") {
            Debug.Log("lerpz"); 
            collidedObject.rigidbody.AddForce(-Vector3.forward);
            Destroy(collidedObject.gameObject, 3.0f); 
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
NullReferenceException
UnityEngine.Rigidbody.AddForce (Vector3 force) (at     
C:/BuildAgent/work/300357e52574df36/Runtime/ExportGenerated/Editor/NewDynamics.cs:492)
CarZombieBehavior.OnCollisionEnter (UnityEngine.Collision collidedObject) (at    
Assets/CarZombieBehavior.js:17)
```

Both "hit" and "lerpz" are printed, but the car runs into the immovable Lerpz (which has a mass of 10 and the car has a mass of 1500) and stops dead in its tracks when it hits Lerpz.

Comment: One person at another site said to use a collision normal.  What exactly is that, and how do I calculate it?

Comment: I tried using velocity and I got the error:                                     NullReferenceException
UnityEngine.Rigidbody.set_velocity (Vector3 value) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/300357e52574df36/Runtime/ExportGenerated/Editor/NewDynamics.cs:396)
CarZombieBehavior.OnCollisionEnter (UnityEngine.Collision collidedObject) (at Assets/CarZombieBehavior.js:22)

Comment: I would suggest you add a: if(collidedObject == null)return; to your code.  It's possible collidedObject has already been destroyed but since you are using a timed destroy the update loop timings are off.